# Odd and even number comparison helper for Handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js, javascript-framework

I am trying to find a way to parse out differently depending array index as odd or even number

I was looking at this http://assemble.io/helpers/helpers-comparison.html and hope to find something like this:

```
{{#each array}}
{{#if_odd {{@index}}}}
    {{this}} is odd 
{{else}}
    {{this}} is even
{{/if_odd}}
{{/each}}
```

I don't really care about the syntax but hope my idea comes across. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Write your own `is_odd` helper and then `{{#is_odd @index}}` should work. Do you know anything about writing helpers? Have you done any research on writing your own helpers?

Comment: Yeah, I guessed using `{{#if_odd {{@index}}}}` is wrong and `{{#if_odd @index}}` is correct. No wonder why I couldn't get it to work originally.

Comment: Check out my own helper implementation for meteor 1.3+, http://stackoverflow.com/a/39175773/2305243 This is intened for Meteor developers only.

Answer (score 27):

I created this helper and it worked

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_even', function(conditional, options) {
  if((conditional % 2) == 0) {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
});
```

Just followed conditional helper here http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

I tried to do this based on `mu is too short` suggestion:

```
{{#if_even @index}}
```