# How do I convert Handlebars isEq helper to Spacebars in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I've had in my Meteor project handlebar helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isEq', function(v1, v2, options){
    if(v1 === v2){
        return options.fn(this);
    }else{
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

But after update to 0.8 and switch from handlebars to spacebars it is not working anymore - I've found in other stackoverflow topic that now I should change `Handlebars.registerHelper` to `UI.registerHelper` but it is still not working - anyone know how to implement this properly for spacebars?

Comment: what happens, does it run this helper?

Comment: I'm getting `Deps` error in the console - something like this: `Exception from Deps recompute function: Spacebars.call(...)` and many, many lines of weird errors that says nothing to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check for equality in Spacebars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650658/check-for-equality-in-spacebars)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use it like the following?

```
{{#isEq 7 8}}
    They're equal!
{{else}}
    They're not equal :(
{{/isEq}}
```

From 0.8, block helpers are defined as templates. See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spacebars#custom-block-helpers

And I think you need to call it with keyword arguments (`{{#isEq v1=7 v2=8}}`). Although, you should be able to define `isEq` as an helper, and then use the `#if` block helper like `{{#if isEq 7 8}}`.

Comment: I've changed my function to return `true` or `false` value and use it like this: `{{#if isEq 2 3}}` and it worked! Thank You.

Answer (score 6):

I use a `UI.registerHelper` to add an `eq` function that can be used in conjunction with `{{#if}}` in `Spacebars`.

In the JavaScript code, I register an `eq` function of two variables that I can call from `Spacebars` (the system that has replaced Handlebars in Meteor v0.8)

```
UI.registerHelper('eq', function(v1, v2, options) {
  if(v1 == v2){
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
});
```

In the HTML, I write:

```
{{#if eq 1 2}}
They are equal.
{{else}}
They're not equal
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I implemented in Meteor 1.3+

```
// JavaScript
Template.registerHelper('odd', function(conditional, options) {
  return conditional % 2;
});

<!-- HTMLS -->
{{#each myCollection}}
{{#if (odd @index)}}
  even
{{else}}
  odd
{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```