# How to IF NOT inside of {{ #each }} template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

How can I render this Meteor Blaze Template ? I would like to use the negative of the IF, but I don't find anywhere how to use it.

```
<ul>
{{#each pages}}
  {{#if (--NOT--) isCover }}
    <li> some content {{value}} </li>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Previous research not found solution
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze
[Check for equality in Spacebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650658/check-for-equality-in-spacebars)

Note: if I use only the `if` statement is working without problem, also I could do and `else` but I would like to have it only with the `if(!isCover)` solution

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to use the `{{#unless}}` block helper.

http://blazejs.org/

```
{{#unless isCover}}
  <li> some content {{value}} </li>
{{/unless}}
```

Comment: Okay, that's a very weird, deviating approach, imho. Would it not have been more easier using `{{#if isCover unless }}`, rather, they've created a whole new tag for that. Not blazing at all

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue, we created a Utility kind of method to invert the boolean values.

```
"invertBoolean" : function (inputValueBoolean) {
    return !inputValueBoolean;
  }
```

which can be used as below

```
 {{#if invertBoolean isCover }}
```