# Meteor : get the opposite statement from a variable into handlebars

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I'm discovering Meteor and was asking myself for a thing.
How in a template can we reverse the boolean into the handlebars from a template ?

There is an example of what I'm trying to do :

**task.html**

```
<li class="{{#if !checked}}checked{{/if}}">
    ...
```

But I'm getting an error "Expected close "}}". Maybe it's not possible.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution : [How to IF NOT inside of {{ #each }} template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182490/how-to-if-not-inside-of-each-template)

Use `{{#unless}}` :

Example of use :

```
{{#unless checked}}
    ....
{{/unless}}
```

Comment: Didn't find anything with my keywords, now I know why.. Thanks !

Comment: All you need to know about Blaze you will find in the guide. Look at: https://guide.meteor.com/blaze.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no `!` syntax handling in the template. 
Neither {{#if !myVar}} nor {{#if not myVar}} worked.

You need to remove `!` from `!checked`:

```
<li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
```

Or you can use `unless`:

```
<li class="{{#unless checked}}checked{{/unless}}">
```

Comment: Yeah, it's weird we can't find it easily in the documentation. Thank you for your response !