# How Do I Create Meteor Template Helper to Check Equality?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

I am making a chat web app.
people can login with facebook and talk (insert message into mongoDB).

showing the text is simple:
javascript:

```
  messages: function () {
    return Messages.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: 1}});
  }
```

each message has these attributes:

```
text: text,
      createdAt: new Date(),            // current time
      owner: Meteor.userId(),           // _id of logged in user
      username: Meteor.user().profile.name
```

It works fine, but I want to "style the message differently" depending on 
whether the message's owner is equal to currentUser (i.e. whether it's my message or others message)

For example, I want my message to be float:right and others message to be float:left

I am thinking the code probably looks something like this:

```
  {{#if mymsg}}
    <div class="msgdiv_my">
       <span class="message">{{text}}</span>
    </div>
  {{else}}
    <div class="msgdiv">
      <span class="message">{{text}}</span>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
```

Where and how to write the mymsg function (which should return True if the `message.owner == currentUser`, and false otherwise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would usually write those checks in a template helper, like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  ownDocument: function (doc) {
    return doc.owner === Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

Then in `myTemplate`, call your helper like this:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#if ownDocument text}}
    <div class="msgdiv_my">
       <span class="message">{{text}}</span>
    </div>
  {{else}}
    <div class="msgdiv">
      <span class="message">{{text}}</span>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Although you may want to implement a global "equals" helper to your meteor app's client, as it sadly is not built in Meteor Spacebars yet:

```
Template.registerHelper('equals',
    function(v1, v2) {
        return (v1 === v2);
    }
);
```

This way, you would call:

```
{{#if equals text.owner currentUser._id}}
```

And get the same result.

KyleMit wrote [a lengthy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28710902/1439597) for all your equality check needs in Meteor.